# Topic Modelling and finding similarity in topics

Tags: topic-modeling, gensim, mallet

Problem statement: I have several documents(20k documents). I need to apply Topic modelling to find similar documents and then analyze those similar documents to find how those are different from each other. 
Q: Could anyone suggest me any Topic modelling package through which I can achieve this. I am exploring Mallet and Gensim Python. Not sure which would best fit in my requirement.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Gensim Python, but MALLET could be a solution. Assuming you have Java expertise, it shouldn't be too difficult.

Create a `cc.mallet.types.InstanceList` with your data and fit a `cc.mallet.topics.SimpleLDA` model. Then, for each `cc.mallet.types.Instance` (Instances are your documents), compute a divergence metric to each other `Instance`. For this, you will need to compute the probability of each topic within each `Instance`, which is slightly tricky. In `SimpleLDA`, there is an `ArrayList<TopicAssignment> data` object that holds `Instances` and their `cc.mallet.topics.TopicAssignment`. A `TopicAssignment` contains a `cc.mallet.types.LabelSequence` called `topicSequence`, which holds the the topic assignment for each word. You will need to loop through this to get counts for each topic. Then, the the probability of topic i in document j is simply (#words assigned to topic i in doc j) / (total words in doc j). Store these probabilities and use them to compute the divergence metric of your choice (e.g., KL divergence).

Answer (score 0):

Mallet is a very easy tool to explore. Instead of using a JAVA implementation of Mallet you can directly execute the binary files which are available here: http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/download.php. You need not even code to generate files like topic distribution in documents. While training topics with mallet using train-topics option, you can specify a file for mallet to write this distribution for you.

After download, just type mallet --help and you can get a list of many things which you can do using mallet. They are self explanatory and very easy to understand.